# gorm one to many relation

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have entities as bellow:

```
type Data struct {
    Receiver string `json:"receiver"`
    Status   string `json:"status"`
    Alerts alerts `json:"alerts" gorm:"foreignKey"`
}

type Alert struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

type alerts []Alert

func (sla *alerts) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(src.([]byte), &sla)
}

func (sla alerts) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    val, err := json.Marshal(sla)
    return string(val), err
}
```

and the migration is as bellow: `db.AutoMigrate(apiV1.Data{}, apiV1.Alert{})`

but when I try to put some value to `data` table. but it act as a `text` with Alerts.
so I can't query on alerts. also `alert` table is empty.

Comment: Hi, by: "but it act as a `text` with Alerts" you mean that inside `data` table there is an `data.Alerts` column with `text` datatype inside?

Comment: @WilliamLuisan yes exactly. (sorry for late response)